# Sylius: How to extend Taxon model?

Tags: php, doctrine, sylius

I'm trying to extend `Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Taxon` by adding new data fields. The same procedure did work on another model outside of Sylius Core. When running `doctrine:migrations:diff`, the error message is "The table with name 'sylius_dev.sylius_taxon' already exists."

The response for `php bin/console debug:container --parameter=sylius.model.taxon.class` does not change at all.

This is my new class in `/src/AppBundle/Entity/FooTaxon.php`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Taxon as BaseTaxon;

class FooTaxon extends BaseTaxon
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $field_one;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFieldOne(): string
    {
        return $this->field_one;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $new_value
     */
    public function setFieldOne(string $new_value): void
    {
        $this->field_one = $new_value;
    }



    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $field_two;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getFieldTwo(): int
    {
        return $this->field_two;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $new_value
     */
    public function setFieldTwo(int $new_value): void
    {
        $this->field_two = $new_value;
    }

}
```

This is my `/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/FooTaxon.orm.yml`:

```
AppBundle\Entity\FooTaxon:
    type: entity
    table: sylius_taxon
    fields:
        field_one:
            type: string
            nullable: false
        field_two:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
```

And here is the new entry in `/app/config/config.yml`:

```
sylius_core:
    resources:
        product_taxon:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\FooTaxon
```

Any help would be appreciated since I'm new to both Symfony and Sylius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this instead of `sylius_core` node:

```
sylius_taxonomy:
    resources:
        taxon:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\FooTaxon
```

And better use upperCase in entity property names instead of snake_case.